# How to create a certificate above an existing certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I have a root certificate with a `Signature algorithm md5RSA` which is currently used by our clients.

I wish to create another root certificate with `Signature algorithm ECDSA SHA-256` that will be above the older certificate in order to be backward compatible (so clients could authenticate with both the older MD5 certificate and the newer SHA-256 certificate using WCF).

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely can't replace any RSA root with any ECDSA one. You _might_ be able to replace it with the _same_ RSA key (if that is large enough for security) and a different hash; crossdupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-ca-without-having-to-reissue- . But since the root signature does not contribute to security, even though md5 signatures have long been insecure, using it on the _root_ should not affect validation. We already have many Qs on that. Do you have an actual problem or is this just aesthetic or checklisty?

Comment: This is an actual problem. Our clients have our services installed on their servers, and our client-application on multiple end-point computers. Each client-application computer has the child certificate installed, so to create an entirely new certificate means to replace all the end-point configuration and install new certificate on each machine.. I wish to avoid that, so some of them can upgrade their software and certificate, while others remain unchanged.

Comment: I don't know if 'the child certificate' is a server cert or client cert (or both) and how many (of each?) there are. But if you want to start using a (new) root with a different key, anything and everything that should trust a cert issued under that new root must have that new root configured. If you use a new (root) cert for the _same_ key, and you either don't use issuer/serial or make it the same, then the relier(s) don't need to change but I don't see any benefit. In particular changing the root cert signature but not the root key accomplishes nothing.